# WebRTC attack surface area?

Tags: web-browser, browser-extensions, webrtc

I'm building an app for browser-to-browser communication.

What is the attack surface area for WebRTC in 2015?

What kinds of attacks could be done?  And more importantly, how do I craft something useful, that does it's reasonable best to be secure?

Here's a list of attacks I've found so far:

Information Leaks:

1. [Leak IP address behind VPN](https://thehackernews.com/2014/06/mozilla-to-provide-webrtc-based-free.html)
2. Persistent monitoring (audio/video).  Browsers work hard on this.
3. Screen sharing [plugins](https://www.webrtc-experiment.com/Pluginfree-Screen-Sharing/).

Remote code execution:

1. Don't run javascript sent from other browsers.  Warn developers and users.
2. Don't open zip, pdf, or other executable files.  Warn users.
3. Searching [Metasploit](https://github.com/rapid7/metasploit-framework/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=webrtc)?
4. Video codec exploits?
5. Remediation by using a browser in a VM.

Here's [some](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Security/Discussions/WebRTC) [discussions](https://bloggeek.me/webrtc-security/) from a couple years ago.

Are there any other obvious attacks?  Where would you start to hack a remote browser to which you have a WebRTC connection?

Answer (score 1):

There is always the possibility of a zero day memory corruption exploit or other exploit.. with any kind of javascript API. I don't really see webrtc as being a huge security threat though. There are easier and more popular targets like flash. I think your list is probably complete, I have seen the VPN "exploit" a while ago, I think that's the only one which was known to be consistently possible, so that seems like a very good track record (so far). I probably would make this a comment, but I am not able to comment.